# Can Postgres raise warnings if joins are inconsistant with foreign keys?

Tags: postgresql

Like most relational databases, PostgreSQL provides foreign keys as a means of providing referential integrity

```
CREATE TABLE job (
  id serial NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
)

CREATE TABLE jobtuning (
  id serial NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
  job_id integer REFERENCES job (id)
)

CREATE TABLE jobstep (
  id serial NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
  jobtuning_id integer REFERENCES jobtuning (id)
)
```

In a case such as this when an intermediate join table is used it becomes very easy to write a query which appears to work, but is wrong:

```
JOIN jobstep ON jobtuning_id=jobtuning.job_id
```

It should be:

```
JOIN jobstep js ON js.jobtuning_id=jobtuning.id
```

One of the strengths of SQL is the ability to form arbitrary relationships, but is it possible to ask Postgres to issue a warning when a join is written that is inconsistent with the way foreign keys or other constraints are defined?

Comment: I suggest you stop naming all your primary keys as `id` and name them with "full" names, e.g. `job_id`, `jobtuning_id`, etc. Then you can use the syntax `jobtuning JOIN jobstep USING (jobtuning_id)` which will make it harder for you to write senseless joins. Even if you keep working with the `ON` syntax, most of the joins will have same column name in the two sides which is easy to get used to and check.

Comment: The only DBMS I know where something like that is possible is DB2. You can define your own data types as "distinct". If you use a different ype for the `job_id`, `jobtunig_id` and `jobstep_id` DB2 would not let you compare a `job_id` against a `jobstep_id`. But unforunately Postgres type system won't let you do something similar.

Comment: Great naming tip! Unfortunately we're Django which has it's own habits (including prefixing the application name to each table).

Answer (score 2):

No.  It is up to the developer/DBA to write sensible joins, in this regard PostgreSQL is just a slave that does what its master commands.

In any case, defining the boundary between joins that make sense and those that don't is not trivial.  If that column is there because of a denormalization, for example, then it perfectly makes sense in spite of a nonexistent foreign key.  You can always decrease the possibility for accidental misjoins by not naming the primary key column just `id` but `jobstep_id`, for example.

Also, when should it emit the warning?  When you hit it with a 1000 line SQL script, containing a hundred statements, out of which 20 contain 'inconsistent' joins?

All in all, this is rather a code review problem than anything else.

Comment: Agreed, developers needs to write sensible joins. I'm in the habit of giving example quiries to coworkers who don't write much SQL, and it appeared that some mistakes might be avoided with a `--warn` flag. Surely good naming conventions would also help.

Answer (score 0):

Kinda. As dezso said if you don't fall down the trap of mixing naming schemes it's easy to manage.

1. Preferably, name all the primary keys `table_id`
2. Or, name all of the primary keys `id`

Either of them work, however the SQL spec and PostgreSQL prefer the former. In the first option you have available to you.

- `NATURAL JOIN`. This will join on all like-named columns. It's a bit too much voodoo for me.
- `JOIN ... USING ( col )`. If all of your join-columns are named by the condition, you can seldom go wrong with this. Perfect amount of voodoo.

Important note, none of these have *anything* to do with `FOREIGN KEY` or `PRIMARY KEY` except by way of naming. So good planning and naming schemes means you can potentially think a bit less on query design and be safer.

Also as a side note, **you don't have to specify the primary key name on table creation in the referencing table (so long as the `PRIMARY KEY` is one column)**

Now, let's see how that looks,

```
CREATE TABLE job (
  job_id serial NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
)
CREATE TABLE jobtuning (
  jobtuning_id serial NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
  job_id integer REFERENCES job -- NOT job (id)
)
CREATE TABLE jobstep (
  jobstep_id serial NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
  jobtuning_id integer REFERENCES jobtuning -- NOT jobtuning (id)
)
```

Query that with a `NATURAL JOIN`

```
SELECT * FROM job
NATURAL JOIN jobtuning
NATURAL JOIN jobstep
```

Or, with a `USING` clause,

```
SELECT * FROM job
JOIN jobtuning USING (job_id)
JOIN jobstep USING (jobtuning_id)
```